# How to make my navigationbar,and toolbar at the bottom to be a single color?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

[image: this is how it looks like]I have an application in which i am using both navigation bar,and toolbar(at the bottom).both having a shade from the center to the bottom.this is how i am creating the toolbar`

```
 [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];



    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -12, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,30);

    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar.png"]];
```

`and i am doing the navigation bar like this`

```
 UIImage *navBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar.png"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBar forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

` Can anybody point me in where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the result you've got right now?

Comment: @NikitaPestrov can u check my edited querry?i want that to be a single color.not want the shadow at the bottom..

Comment: why you not create UIView with gradient color that's look like UINavigationBar.

Comment: And what is the result you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to create a 1x1 UIImage and then set it as the background image for the navigation bar and the toolbar. This will eliminate the gradient and make both bars one solid color of your choosing. Here's an example:

```
UIImage *image = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

And if you want to get rid of the shadow cast beneath the navigation bar, this works for me:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setClipsToBounds:YES];
```